# what is the difference between django html_message and message in send mail

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

When im trying to send a mail with django send mail only the html message is coming and not the normal message i want to know the difference between both.
  Is there any best way to send mails through template or html files because i want a comming mailing system in my app.

Note:- the difference is of more important.

**THIS IS WHAT I DID**

msg_html = (' **HELLLOOOOO**')
msg_plain = 'Normalallalaa

send_mail("titleeeee", msg_plain,"sender@test",["reciever@tese",],html_message=msg_html)

**My mail contained only Hello in bold**

Where did my message go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message is plain text, while html_message is a message formatted using HTML. If you set both, probably your email client is displaying the HTML version.

Comment: Means d priority is for html one... and if i recieve a mail via terminal den il get the text mail right since it wont have a html to display...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that some (old or specifically configured) email clients won't display HTML messages, therefore you need to make sure all your users can read your emails properly. If you decide to send just text, then users capable of getting HTML messages won't benefit from it.

This is the strategy I follow:

I use `django.template.loader.render_to_string` to render a template with a given context. The value this function returns is a string with a message in HTML.

```
html_text = render_to_string(template, context)
```

Then I create a plain text message based on the HTML message (for instance, by using a package named `html2text`):

```
plain_text = html2text(html_text)
```

And finally I send the email with `django.core.mail.send_mail`, passing `html_text` and `plain_text` as parameters.

Comment: got it.... thnx alot... and if i recieve a mail via terminal den il get the text mail right since it wont have a html to display...